# How would I solve this equation for $X$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Just wondering how I would go about solving (or finding possible solutions) an equation of the following form:
$$
{\ddot{X}}+\frac{1}{t}\dot{X}=0
$$
Is this a second-order non-linear differential equation?

I'm guessing I would separate the variables, but I have done this and it is not giving me what I am expecting...

Comment: Is $a$ constant? If so then consider $y=\dot{X}$, then the equation is first order linear (or even separable), then integrate $y$. If $a$ depends only on $t$ then what I said still works but it is not trivial. If $a$ depends on $X$ in some way then you have a real difficulty.

Comment: That's what I've done. I'm expecting X proportional to ln(t)

Comment: I should modify this, a should actually EQUAL t.

Comment: $X(t)= A \log t + B$ is a solution for all $A,B \in \Bbb{R}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you multiply both sides by $t$, you get

$$tX''+X'=(tX')'=0$$
$$tX'=c_1,X'=\frac{c_1}t$$
$$X=c_1\ln t+c_2$$

If you wished to do it by separation of variables, you should get

$$\frac{X''}{X'}=-\frac1t$$
$$\ln|X'|=\ln|\frac1t|+c$$

which should yield something similar.